# Setting values of bytearray

Tags: visual-c++, arrays, typedef

I have a BYTE data[3]. The first element, data[0] has to be a BYTE with very specific values which are as follows:

```
typedef enum
{
SET_ACCURACY=0x01,
SET_RETRACT_LIMIT=0x02,
SET_EXTEND_LIMT=0x03,
SET_MOVEMENT_THRESHOLD=0x04,
SET_STALL_TIME= 0x05,
SET_PWM_THRESHOLD= 0x06,
SET_DERIVATIVE_THRESHOLD= 0x07,
SET_DERIVATIVE_MAXIMUM = 0x08,
SET_DERIVATIVE_MINIMUM= 0x09,
SET_PWM_MAXIMUM= 0x0A,
SET_PWM_MINIMUM = 0x0B,
SET_PROPORTIONAL_GAIN = 0x0C,
SET_DERIVATIVE_GAIN= 0x0D,
SET_AVERAGE_RC = 0x0E,
SET_AVERAGE_ADC = 0x0F,
GET_FEEDBACK=0x10,
SET_POSITION=0x20,
SET_SPEED= 0x21,
DISABLE_MANUAL = 0x30,
RESET= 0xFF,
}TYPE_CMD;
```

As is, if I set `data[0]=SET_ACCURACY` it doesn't set it to `0x01`, it sets it to `1`, which is not what I want. data[0] must take the value 0x01 when set it equal to SET_ACCURACY. How do I make it so that it does this for not only SET_ACCURACY, but all the other values as well?

EDIT: Actually this works... I had a different error in my code that I attributed to this. Sorry!

Thanks!

Comment: What?! `0x01` and `1` are the same number! What do you mean? `0x01` is just the hexadecimal representation of the number `1`.

Comment: yea thats what I thought.... I need to take another look at my program... maybe I am using typedef incorrectly?

Comment: No! I think nothing is incorrect. You are getting the same thing you put into the array.

Comment: wow.... I am a dunce.... I totally had it right the whole time... O.K. well thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"`data[0]=SET_ACCURACY` doesn't set it to `0x01`, it sets it to `1`"***

It assigns value of `SET_ACCURACY` to the `data[0]`, which means that bits `00000001` are stored into memory at address `&data[0]`. `0x01` is hexadecimal representation of this byte, `1` is its decimal representation.